# Using crontab to execute script every hour for 24 hours

Tags: php, sql, cron, jobs

I need to know how i can able to run  php cron script file for every hour . than after 24 hour db update from active user to expire user something like i want to add some information after every 1 hour than closed these after 24 hour how i can do that any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To execute a PHP script every 24 hours, you can use @daily or 0 0 * * * followed by the location of the PHP binary executable, the -q flag, and the path of the .php file:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php -q script_directory/cron.php
```